# SELECT FROM inner query slowdown

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have two very similar queries, one takes 22 seconds the other takes 6 seconds. Both use an inner select, have the exact same outer columns and outer joins. The only difference is the inner select that the outer query is using to join in on.

The inner query when run alone executes in 100ms or less in both cases and returns the EXACT SAME data.

Both queries as a whole have a lot of room for improvement, but this particular oddity is really puzzling to us and we just want to understand why. To me it would seem the inner query should be executed once in 100ms then the outer stuff happens. I have a feeling the inner select may be executed multiple times.

Query that takes 6 seconds:

```
SELECT {whole bunch of column names}

FROM (
        SELECT projectItems.* FROM projectItems

        WHERE projectItems.isActive = 1

        ORDER BY projectItemsID ASC
        OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
    ) projectItems

LEFT JOIN categories
    ON projectItems.fk_category = categories.categoryID
...{more joins}
```

Query that takes 22 seconds:

```
SELECT {whole bunch of column names}

FROM (
        SELECT projectItems.* FROM projectItems

        WHERE projectItems.isActive = 1
        AND projectItemsID = 6539
    ) projectItems

LEFT JOIN categories
    ON projectItems.fk_category = categories.categoryID
...{more joins}
```

Comment: Have you thought about comparing `Execution Plans` for both of these queries?

Comment: Doing that now, they are both beasts

Comment: I suspect when you look at the Execution Plan, you'll see that the first inner select is providing a hint that only a single row is being returned (`OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY` is effectively the same as `TOP(1)`).

Answer (score 0):

For every row in your projectItems table, in the second function, you search two columns instead of one. If projectItemsID isn't the primary key or if it isn't indexed, it takes longer to parse an extra column.'

If you look at the sizes of the tables and the number of rows each query returns, you can calculate how many comparisons need to be made for each of the queries.

Comment: projectItemsID is a primary key. I understand that the extra compare is slower but that inner query runs solo for both cases in less than 100ms. I don't think that extra column comparison should be adding over 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you're right that the inner query is being run for every single row that is being left joined with categories.

I can't find a proper source on it right now, but you can easily test this by doing something like this and comparing the run times.  Here, we can at least be sure that the inner query is only running one time. (sorry if any syntax is incorrect, but you'll get the general idea):

```
DECLARE @innerQuery TABLE ( [all inner query columns here] )
INSERT INTO @innerQuery
SELECT projectItems.* FROM projectItems
WHERE projectItems.isActive = 1
    AND projectItemsID = 6539

SELECT {whole bunch of field names}

FROM @innerQuery as IQ

LEFT JOIN categories
    ON IQ.fk_category = categories.categoryID
...{more joins}
```

Comment: Isn't using a CTE easier than a variable?

Comment: We tested this and it does run in 6 seconds like the other one now. Do you know why SQL server wants to redo that inner query over and over again? Is there a way to give it some kind of hint so it doesn't?

Comment: @Hogan Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Sean256 it is not "re-doing" the inner query.

Comment: @hogan I'm having a similiar result on a different data set, would you mind elaborating why the big time difference if the sub query isn't being executed multiple times?

Comment: Because of the offset command.. it does a seek and not a scan... Look at the execution plan.  I can't say what is going on with other queries until I see them

Comment: If it isn't "re-doing" the inner query, then how is it possible the inner queries between the two take approximately the same amount of time (sub 100 ms) to run?

For example: his scan would only have to happen once, or his seek would only have to happen once. Both cost relatively the same amount of time. I don't have his execution plan.

Comment: i'd try `SELECT projectItems.* INTO #tempItem FROM projectItems` before i typed out all those columns for a table variable

Comment: @Hogan Yes that would be easier than a variable.  I didn't know you could do that in SQL, thanks for enlightening me!

Comment: @KevinLayfield CTEs are the best thing ever.